# Can programs be written that can quit from Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

If I visit a site, I want to close the Chrome Web Browser. Is it possible to write such a program?

Comment: The answer I've posted refers to web applications - but if you're talking about native applications, the answer could be different. For instance, if you're talking about writing a program in Windows / Linux / MacOS that can close the Chrome browser., the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal operation, this should not be possible. However, there have been cases where browsers have had well known bugs that could be exploited. To be clear though, I'm referring to crashing the browser. There is no supported API or method of asking the browser to close.

For instance, a simple line of CSS could crash Internet Explorer 6. Something like this on Chrome would probably not work anyways, since Chrome runs each tab in its own process.

There *is* a way to close a browser window (tab) via script if your script opened the window, simply by calling `window.close()` (where window is the child window). Please see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close for more information.